# VB.Net/C# - Split string on custom function

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I'm working on a custom mathematical expression calculator, but I'm having problems at parsing nested conditional expression like this one:

```
IIF("M"="M",(IIF(100 < 50,(IIF(2 > 0.45,2,1)),(IIF(2 > 0.45,4,3)))),(IIF(100 < 46,(IIF(2 > 0.45,2,1)),(IIF(2 >0.45,4,3)))))
```

What I'd like to do is to split the IIF function by commas in order to get its parameters:

```
Dim condition = "M"="M"
Dim truePart = (IIF(100 < 50,(IIF([2 > 0.45,2,1)),(IIF(2 >0.45,4,3))))
Dim falsePart = (IIF(100 < 46,(IIF(2 > 0.45,2,1)),(IIF(2 >0.45,4,3)))))
```

At the moment I'm using Regex to parse single IIF function by getting what is inside the parentheses and the split it by commas:

```
\((.*?)\)
```

Obviously that doesn't work with such expression since it will stop at the first closing parentheses, therefore I thought about using this to get all the other characters:

```
\((.*?)\).*
```

But now I'm not sure how to split it, since using commas is not an option anymore.

Comment: If you want to parse it, write a parser..

Comment: I don't get the benefit of this kind of answer. I did write a parser, but I'm having trouble parsing the type of expressions I specified above.

Comment: Well, you may use something like [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=IIF%5c%28%28%3f%3a%2c%3f%28%5c%28%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%28%29%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%5c%28%29%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%5c%29%29%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%5c%29%7c%5b%5e%2c%5d%2b%29%2b%29*%5c%29&i=IIF%28%22M%22%3d%22M%22%2c%28IIF%28100+%3c+50%2c%28IIF%282+%3e+0.45%2c2%2c1%29%29%2c%28IIF%282+%3e+0.45%2c4%2c3%29%29%29%29%2c%28IIF%28100+%3c+46%2c%28IIF%282+%3e+0.45%2c2%2c1%29%29%2c%28IIF%282+%3e0.45%2c4%2c3%29%29%29%29%29) but it does not look right. Does not look like a right job for a regex.

Comment: I'd like to get the three parameters of the first IIF function (condition, truePart, falsePart) exactly as I wrote them above.

Comment: A side note use the `IF` operator, not `IIF`...

Comment: @Codexer thanks for the tip, but that's just how the expression I need to parse was written at the time. It wouldn't make any difference in this case since I manually evaluate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from theory is that regular expressions are not capable to do what you requested because they "cannot count". However, you need to count.

The practise says that .NET regular expressions are no regular expressions but stack machines. With a group `(?<Group>.*)` you in fact add an entry to a stack of that group. With `(?<-Group>)`, you can remove an entry from that stack. You can also test whether the stack is empty.

Out of curiosity, I gave it a try and I believe that

`[\(,]([^\(\)]|(?<Par>\()|(?<-Par>\)))*(?(Par)---|[,\)])`

should work, where `---` is used as an escape sequence. If you understand that "regular expression" right away, then I think you are good to go. In all other cases, I would rather recommend you to write a parser manually. Otherwise, you are not going to understand your code 5min after you have tested it.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I ended up manually parsing the expression since it will be more readable in case I need to change something in the future.